# Make kinesis stream accept multiple consumers

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

I have a stream "dest" for which I want two consumers and the same message should be consumed by both the streams.

But If one stream consumes the message then the message is lost and doesn't go to the second stream. I don't want queue but topic here.

I tried creating 2 different groups for 2 different streams but didn't help.
How can I configure it here?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          group: group1
          destination: dest
          content-type: application/json

spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          group: group2
          destination: dest
          content-type: application/json



spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          destination: dest
          content-type: application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare two different bindings for that use-case `input1` and `input2`:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input1:
          group: group1
          destination: dest
          content-type: application/json

spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input2:
          group: group2
          destination: dest
          content-type: application/json
```

This way two different consumers are going to be created by the binder and, therefore, both of them are going to consume the same record from Kinesis stream.

Of course, you would need to have two different `@StreamListener` configuration for each binding target.